# How to replace objects with pronouns? Is the following correct?

Tags: pronoun

> Ich gebe meiner Oma ein Stück Kuchen.

So replacing "ein Stück Kuchen", is the following correct?

> Ich gebe meiner Oma es.

Comment: "Ich gebe meiner Oma es" sounds more like "(I don't give it to my father,) i'll give it to my granny (instead)!" ... I'd use "Ich gebe es meiner Oma" instead

Answer (score 8):

> Ich gebe meiner Oma ein Stück Kuchen.
>
> <s>Ich gebe meiner Oma **es**.</s> *(only poetical)*

No, it has to be

> Ich gebe **es** meiner Oma.

If there's a personal pronoun in the row of objects, it leads the row:

> Ich gebe **ihr** ein Stück Kuchen. *(meiner Oma → ihr)*

If there are multiple personal pronouns as objects, the order is accusative, dative, genitive:

> Ich gebe **es** **ihr**.

Comment: "Ich gebe ihr es" is also perfectly fine, I'd say. Only a slight difference in emphasis. And yours is of course more common.

Comment: I first thought the same but now I think that's just sloppy speech. With the accusative-genitive order, it sticks out even more: *Ich erinnere mich dessen.*

Comment: "Ich erinnere dessen mich" is definitely weird, agreed. Maybe "ihr es" really is just sloppy as well. This touches the philosophical question of what is "proper" German and what isn't (Duden rules vs. language community convention).

Comment: oh so for any situation, if there is a personal pronoun of multiple objects, the personal pronoun will precede the other objects? Also, how would you replace zum Artz in the following sentence? Mueller hat seine Oma zum Arzt gefahren.

Comment: **Ich gebe ihr eines** - fehlt noch.

Comment: @J.Wilshere Er hat sie zu ihm gefahren.